# getting cannot implicitly convery type error for return View(lstEmployee);

Tags: asp.net

Getting error on `return View(lstEmployee);`

error details:

> Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult' to
>   'UserRegistration.Controllers.IActionResult'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)    UserRegistration    C:\Users\rcroh\Desktop\Spring 18\DIS\Final
>   project\DSP Final Project Group
>   12\UserRegistration\UserRegistration\Controllers\EmployeeController.cs    21  Active

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using UserRegistration.Models;

namespace UserRegistration.Controllers
{

public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
        EmployeeDataAccessLayer objemployee = new EmployeeDataAccessLayer();

        // GET: /<controller>/  
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Employee> lstEmployee = new List<Employee>();
            lstEmployee = objemployee.GetAllEmployees().ToList();
           //G
            return View(lstEmployee);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create([Bind] Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                objemployee.AddEmployee(employee);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(employee);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The error says you have a type named `UserRegistration.Controllers.IActionResult`. Don't just spam out quick fixes, understand what they do and be aware of your whole project.

Comment: Are you using Core MVC or standard MVC? Check all references and dependencies first to find out your MVC project type, then we can analyze why the error occurred.